# RegEx: For restricting total length of alphanumeric characters including all the group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written the regex for select the alphanumeric characters that should satisfy the following conditions.

1. it can start either start with a-z or 0-9.
2. it can have maximum two '-' or maximum two space character.
3. The length should be 10 excluding the '-'  and space.

   ```
   /(^([a-z]|[0-9])*)[-\s]?(([a-z]|[0-9])*)[-\s]?(([a-z]|[0-9])*)$/i
   ```

this will meet the above two conditions but it will selects the string that is more the 10 alphanumeric too.

any thought on this.

Comment: `maximum two '-' or maximum two space character.` does that include having one space and one dash? Or is it either spaces or dashes, at most two of the chosen one?

Comment: `it can start either start with a-z or 0-9.` Are trailing characters allowed to be other than these?

Comment: *start with a-z* - if it starts with lowercase alphanumeric character, then why are you using the `i` (case-insensitive) flag?

Comment: 4.it should not allow combination of '-' and space character

Comment: it should not allow '-' or space in starting and ending of the string

Answer (score 2):

The desired result can be achieved more easily by JavaScript String methods.

**Details:**

- [`String.match(RegExp)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) - extract every character from the `String` object which satisfies the pattern provided by the `RegExp` object. **Returns** an array containing the matches.
- [`Array.join(separator)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) - Joins every item in a String array with the given *separator*.

*(extractor)*

- `\w+` - matches *1 or more* repetitions of *alphanumeric* character.

*(validator)*

- `^` - matches the *start* of a string.
- `[\-\s]` - matches `'-'` or `' '` *once*.
- `\w*` - matches *0 or more* repetitions of *alphanumeric* character.
- `$` - matches the *end* of a string.

```js
let verify = str => {
  if(validator.test(str)) {
    let len = str.match(extractor).join('').length;
    console.log(len == 10 ? 'Valid!' : 'Invalid!');
  } else 
    console.log('Invalid!');
}

let str1 = '24-carat magic';
let str2 = 'Shape of you';

let extractor = /\w+/g;
let validator = /^\w+[\-\s]\w*[\-\s]\w*$/;

verify(str1);
verify(str2);
```

Comment: The first character could be one of `A-Z` or `_` (your second string shouldn't be valid as per OP's first rule ; although he's using the `i` flag in his regex so I'm not sure). Moreover while this would accept one or two spaces or dashes, it would also accept also a mix of them (which is unclear whether it'd be ok or not), or worse any non-word character.

Comment: @Aaron The OP says it *can't* start with `_`. Btw, thanks for pointing out that I also have to care about 2nd and 3rd point!

Comment: What I meant is that `\w` also matches `_` : it's equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`

Comment: @rv7 I have used your code and added my improvments it is working.

Comment: @MohanaRajesh Glad to know it! Feel free in querying further.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following regex:

```
/^(?!(?:.*?[ -]){3,})(?:[a-z0-9][ -]?){1,10}$/
```

Explanation:

`^` starts at start of string

`(?!` starts a negative look ahead

`(?:` starts a non capturing Group

`.*?` look for zero or more of any char (non greedy)

`[ -]` look for the restricted chars

`{3,}` look for 3 or more of that Group (negative lookahead)

`(?:` start a non capturing Group

`[a-z0-9][ -]?` match one character/digit followed by an optional restricted char

`{1,10}` match 1 to 10 of that Group

`$` match the end of string

The tricks: Using neagtive lookahead will restrict the chars.

Using '`(?:[a-z0-9][ -]?)`' will count only letters/digit - not the restricted char.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work :

```
^[a-z0-9]([^- ]{9}|(?=[^- ]*-[^- ]*$).{10}|(?=[^- ]*-[^- ]*-[^- ]*$).{11}|(?=[^- ]* [^- ]*$).{10}|(?=[^- ]* [^- ]* [^- ]*$).{11})$
```

That is one character of a-z or 0-9 followed by either :

- 9 characters that are neither spaces nor dashes
- 10 characters, exactly one of them being a dash, none of them being a space
- 11 characters, exactly two of them being dashes, none of them being a space
- 10 characters, exactly one of them being a space, none of them being a dash
- 11 characters, exactly two of them being spaces, none of them being a dash

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/GZzOQ7/2).

Of course this is all a bit awful and I would discourage you from using a regex for that validation if you can help it.

Answer (score 0):

@rv7 added extra checking in your answer

```
let verify = str => {
  if (validator.test(str)) {
    let len = str.match(extractor).join('').length;
    if (len === 10) {
      if (dashvalidator.test(str)) {
        let dashLength = str.match(dashvalidator).join('').length;
        if (dashLength === 2) {
          console.log('dashvalidator valid')
        } else {
          console.log('dashvalidator Invalid!');
        }
      } else {
        if (spaceValidator.test(str)) {
          str = str.replace(/\s/g, '*');
          let spaceLength = str.match(spaceValidatorHelp).join('').length;
          if (spaceLength === 2) {
            console.log('spaceValidatorHelp valid')
          } else {
            console.log('spaceValidatorHelp Invalid!');
          }
        } else {
          console.log('valid!');
        }
      }
    } else {
      console.log('Invalid!');
    }
  } else
    console.log('Invalid!');
}

let str1 = '24-carat magic';
let str2 = '12 34567 890';

let extractor = /\w+/g;
let validator = /^\w+[\-\s]?\w*[\-\s]?\w*$/;
let dashvalidator = /-/g;
let spaceValidatorHelp = /\*/g;
let spaceValidator = /\s/g;



verify(str1);
verify(str2);
```

I have added the conditions checking

1. One '-' and one space not allowed in the string.
2. It should have no special character or should have two '-' or should have two space character